# dplyr: group_by() based on value AND Position in column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataset with the columns `start`, `end` and `type`:

```
structure(list(number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), start = structure(c(1121472000, 
1184544000, 1196467200, 1186963200, 1199145600, 1228089600, 1232582400, 
1233446400, 1246406400, 1262304000, 1271030400, 1285891200, 1293840000, 
1344211200, 1367366400, 1413158400, 1427846400, 1441065600, 1451952000, 
1461542400, 1464739200, 1491004800, 1501545600, 1506816000, 1509494400, 
1548979200, 1557705600, 1561939200, 1572825600, 1590969600, 1606780800
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), end = structure(c(1184457600, 
1196380800, 253402214400, 1199059200, 1228003200, 1232496000, 
1233360000, 1246320000, 1262217600, 1270944000, 1285804800, 1293753600, 
1344124800, 1367280000, 1413072000, 1427760000, 1440979200, 1451865600, 
1461456000, 1464652800, 1490918400, 1501459200, 1506729600, 1509408000, 
1548892800, 1557619200, 1561852800, 1572739200, 1590883200, 1606694400, 
253402214400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", 
    "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "D", "E", "E", "F", "E", "E", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E")), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
tail(data, 20)

   number start               end                 type
    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>   
 1      1 2010-10-01 00:00:00 2010-12-31 00:00:00 D       
 2      1 2011-01-01 00:00:00 2012-08-05 00:00:00 D       
 3      1 2012-08-06 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00 D       
 4      1 2013-05-01 00:00:00 2014-10-12 00:00:00 E       
 5      1 2014-10-13 00:00:00 2015-03-31 00:00:00 D       
 6      1 2015-04-01 00:00:00 2015-08-31 00:00:00 E       
 7      1 2015-09-01 00:00:00 2016-01-04 00:00:00 E       
 8      1 2016-01-05 00:00:00 2016-04-24 00:00:00 F       
 9      1 2016-04-25 00:00:00 2016-05-31 00:00:00 E       
10      1 2016-06-01 00:00:00 2017-03-31 00:00:00 E       
11      1 2017-04-01 00:00:00 2017-07-31 00:00:00 E       
12      1 2017-08-01 00:00:00 2017-09-30 00:00:00 E       
13      1 2017-10-01 00:00:00 2017-10-31 00:00:00 E       
14      1 2017-11-01 00:00:00 2019-01-31 00:00:00 E       
15      1 2019-02-01 00:00:00 2019-05-12 00:00:00 E       
16      1 2019-05-13 00:00:00 2019-06-30 00:00:00 E       
17      1 2019-07-01 00:00:00 2019-11-03 00:00:00 E       
18      1 2019-11-04 00:00:00 2020-05-31 00:00:00 E       
19      1 2020-06-01 00:00:00 2020-11-30 00:00:00 E       
20      1 2020-12-01 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00 E
```

**Question:**

I want to summarise the data based on the group of column type **but** I want the groups to be only for adjacent rows of the same value.
The relevant column here is `type`, where I want to group not only based on the value itslef e.g. "E", or "D", but also group based on the position (only group adjacend values of "D", "E", etc. together.

As of now I could obviously use:

```
> data_mre %>%
+   group_by(number, type) %>%
+   summarise(start = dplyr::first(start),
+             end = dplyr::last(end),
+             .groups = "drop")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  number type  start               end                
   <dbl> <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1      1 A     2005-07-16 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
2      1 B     2007-08-13 00:00:00 2009-01-21 00:00:00
3      1 C     2009-01-22 00:00:00 2009-01-31 00:00:00
4      1 D     2009-02-01 00:00:00 2015-03-31 00:00:00
5      1 E     2013-05-01 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
6      1 F     2016-01-05 00:00:00 2016-04-24 00:00:00
```

But this would build groups that overlap the rows and dont take the position within the rows into account. Is there a way that I could also take the row as an argument in the `group_by()`statement?

This is what I imagine the result should look like:

```
  number type  start               end                
   <dbl> <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1      1 A     2005-07-16 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
2      1 B     2007-08-13 00:00:00 2009-01-21 00:00:00
3      1 C     2009-01-22 00:00:00 2009-01-31 00:00:00
4      1 D     2009-02-01 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00
5      1 E     2013-05-01 00:00:00 2014-10-12 00:00:00
6      1 D     2014-10-13 00:00:00 2015-03-31 00:00:00
5      1 E     2015-04-01 00:00:00 2016-01-04 00:00:00
6      1 F     2016-01-05 00:00:00 2016-04-24 00:00:00
5      1 E     2016-04-25 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide the output you expect from your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I added the expected output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::rleid`

Using tidy/dplyr:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(group = data.table::rleid(type)) %>%
  summarize(number= first(number), type = first(type), start=first(start), end=last(end)) %>% 
  select(!group)
```

Ouput:

```
  number type  start               end                
   <dbl> <chr> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1      1 A     2005-07-16 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
2      1 B     2007-08-13 00:00:00 2009-01-21 00:00:00
3      1 C     2009-01-22 00:00:00 2009-01-31 00:00:00
4      1 D     2009-02-01 00:00:00 2013-04-30 00:00:00
5      1 E     2013-05-01 00:00:00 2014-10-12 00:00:00
6      1 D     2014-10-13 00:00:00 2015-03-31 00:00:00
7      1 E     2015-04-01 00:00:00 2016-01-04 00:00:00
8      1 F     2016-01-05 00:00:00 2016-04-24 00:00:00
9      1 E     2016-04-25 00:00:00 9999-12-31 00:00:00
```

Using data.table

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, .(
  number=first(number),
  start = first(start), 
  end = last(end), 
  type = first(type)
  ), 
  by=.(rleid(type))][,.(number, type, start, end )]
```

Output

```
   number   type      start        end
    <num> <char>     <POSc>     <POSc>
1:      1      A 2005-07-16 9999-12-31
2:      1      B 2007-08-13 2009-01-21
3:      1      C 2009-01-22 2009-01-31
4:      1      D 2009-02-01 2013-04-30
5:      1      E 2013-05-01 2014-10-12
6:      1      D 2014-10-13 2015-03-31
7:      1      E 2015-04-01 2016-01-04
8:      1      F 2016-01-05 2016-04-24
9:      1      E 2016-04-25 9999-12-31
```